# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError while using Http2SolrClient builder with solr 9+?

Tags: java, solr

I am using `maven` with my project and this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java version: `17`

SpringBootVersion: `2.7.13`

Usage in code:

```
@Bean
public SolrClient solrClient() {
  return new Http2SolrClient.Builder(host).build();
}
```

I have the correct host working with `HttpSolrClient`(deprecated) but not with `Http2SolrClient`.

Build OK - Error on App run:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpFields$Mutable
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient$Builder.<init> 
(Http2SolrClient.java:992)
```

I tried to add any version of `org.eclipse.jetty` - not helped.

In docs - version 9.2.0 should support Http2SolrClient:
https://solr.apache.org/docs/9_2_0/solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/Http2SolrClient.html

How to correctly create a working Http2SolrClient?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I found an answer, the issue is consulted several months ago here:

[https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-16668?jql=text%20~%20%22Http2SolrClient%20HttpFields%22](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-16668?jql=text%20%7E%20%22Http2SolrClient%20HttpFields%22)

So `"forcing all the jetty dependencies to a specific version"` is working for this case:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
implementation group: 'org.apache.solr', name: 'solr-solrj', version: '9+'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.http2', name: 'http2-client', version: '10.0.13'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.http2', name: 'http2-common', version: '10.0.13'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.http2', name: 'http2-hpack', version: '10.0.13'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.http2', name: 'http2-http-client-transport', version: '10.0.13'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-util', version: '10.0.13'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-io', version: '10.0.13'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-http', version: '10.0.13'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-client', version: '10.0.13'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-alpn-client', version: '10.0.13'
implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-alpn-java-client', version: '10.0.13'
}
```

`" the problem I have with SolrJ 9.2.0 is caused somehow by Spring Boot, because they override the version of Jetty."`